# :after and :before are collapsing?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, visual-glitch

Reference: http://www.stephenkelzer.com/design.html

**Optimized for firefox only** so far (may find extra bugs if viewing in other browsers

--First time poster guys, I could really use some help here, Thanks!

---

I am building a really simple portfolio page here, I plan to expand on it later.

I want to add a layered effect to each module like Chris Coyier did on his site: http://css-tricks.com/

**I have made the layers green and yellow to help them stand out**

HTML markup:

```
<div id="mh-com" class="abc portmodule">
    <div class="portmoduleimg"></div>
        <div class="portmoduleinfo">
            <h3><a href="http://www.marlonheimerl.com/" rel="nofollow">MarlonHeimerl.com</a></h3>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="business-template" class="zxc portmodule">
    <div class="portmoduleimg"></div>
        <div class="portmoduleinfo">
            <h3><a href="" rel="nofollow">Business Template</a></h3>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS markup:

```
.portmodule {
margin-top: 25px;
height:300px;
overflow: hidden;
width:969px;
background-color:rgb(98, 109, 111);
color: rgb(192,204,206);
}
.portmodule:after, .portmodule:before {
content:"";
position: absolute;
top:6px;
left:6px;
background-color: green;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index: -1;
}
.portmodule:before {
top:12px;
left:12px;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

---

I want to make it so that each separate module has a layered effect to it. I hope you guys can help me out! Thank you!

Comment: What is the glitch? Appears correctly in my firefox and chrome. Are you just wanting to add depth to it like CSS shadows?

Comment: Btw, this is a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/qjWbu/ Please use these in your posts. As you can see, the code provided doesn't help us much. The people on here are quick to down vote, so you'll need to ask clear Q and A style questions to avoid them.

Comment: My goal is to have each module have its own ':before' and ':after' layer.

in otherwords, I would like there to be a break in the green and yellow colors between to the two modules.

the :before & :after code is linked to 2 separate ".portmodule" classes and hence should be shown twice separately, but instead it is combining them into one tall :before:after element.

Comment: here is an example like you asked:http://codepen.io/thestevekelzer/pen/bAkIH

Comment: Much easier to help with that, thank you. (`.portmodule` is at the bottom of CSS for future readers). I've tried using a bottom margin on the `.portmodule:before`, adding a spacer between the two boxes, even wrapping them in separate containers and padding that. I think it's an issue with pseudo elements, I noticed on the demo link that he did not have them separating like that (it's two completely different sets of element styles). I also noticed his first one (the top left logo) is positioned absolutely. Maybe use a border sprite? Good luck.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you!
for starters, I think I will just take the 'ID' route and make each module independent from one another. Might muffle of my CSS for a little while until I get it figured out, but thats what you get when you find a design that you really like!

Ill follow up if/when I find a solution!

Thanks Again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codepen.io/thestevekelzer/pen/ibmta

I have found a 'minor-solution'...
By that I mean that I don't consider this a preferred method.

It seems that the absolute positioning of the :before & :after pseudo-elements is all based on the parent element, not the child element like I thought.
You will notice in my forked codepen that I have increased the top adjustment for the 'business-template' element to accommodate it being lower on the page.

I would still love it if someone knows a more simple solution. Thank you!!!